# In GoodData can I customize the layout of a dashboard tab?

Tags: customization, dashboard, gooddata

Specifically, I want to layout the list of tabs vertically in the nav bar on the left side rather than have them go horizontally? How much customization can I do to the Dashboard and the tabs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is unfortunately currently not available by "customization". You cannot select it but, we are working on new layouts that will most probably have vertical navigation bar for dashboard tabs. Stay tuned!

JT

Answer (score 1):

Possible workaround is to implement your own navigation
 - Instead of tabs create separate (single tab) dashboards
 - build your own tab navigation outside GoodData, make it to display different dashboards when clicking on tabs

You can even do your own filtering outside GoodData and distribute it to the iframe with link like this 
https://secure.gooddata.com/dashboard.html?label.dataset.name=FILTER_WILDCARD#project=/gdc/projects/PID&dashboard=/gdc/md/PID/obj/ID"

use embed dialogue to build the URL specific for you

EDIT: you can now hide the tabs in embedded mode using *nochrome* param and direct user to go to specific tab using *tab* param. So it is possible to create your own tab navigation around the embedded dashboard.

The embedding options are described here:
https://developer.gooddata.com/article/embedded-dashboard-events